# CNN on Fashion MNIST dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I am using the fashion MNIST dataset to try to work this out. I am using the data from the links:

Training : 
http://fashion-mnist.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz

training set labels: 
http://fashion-mnist.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz

test set images 
http://fashion-mnist.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz

test set labels 
http://fashion-mnist.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz

I use the code to open the dataset:

```py
def load_mnist(path, kind='train'):
    import os
    import gzip
    import numpy as np

    """Load MNIST data from `path`"""
    labels_path = os.path.join(path,
                               '%s-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz'
                               % kind)
    images_path = os.path.join(path,
                               '%s-images-idx3-ubyte.gz'
                               % kind)

    with gzip.open(labels_path, 'rb') as lbpath:
        labels = np.frombuffer(lbpath.read(), dtype=np.uint8,
                               offset=8)

    with gzip.open(images_path, 'rb') as imgpath:
        images = np.frombuffer(imgpath.read(), dtype=np.uint8,
                               offset=16).reshape(len(labels), 784)

    return images, labels

label = ['T-shirt/top',  'Trouser', 'Pullover', 'Dress', 'Coat', 'Sandal', 'Shirt',
         'Sneaker', 'Bag', 'Ankle boot']

data_dir = './'
X_train, y_train = load_mnist('D:\book', kind='train')
X_test, y_test = load_mnist('D:\book', kind='t10k')

X_train = X_train.astype(np.float32) / 256.0
X_test = X_test.astype(np.float32) / 256.0
```

I am trying to build a Convolutional Neural Network with the following architecture:

- Convolutional Layer with 32 filters with size of 3x3
- ReLU activation function
- 2x2 MaxPooling
- Convolutional Layer with 64 filters with size of 3x3
- ReLU activation function
- 2x2 MaxPooling
- Fully connected layer with 512 units and ReLU activation function
- Softmax activation layer for output layer
  For 100 epochs using the SGD optimizer

My Code is:

```py
X_train = X_train.reshape([60000, 28, 28, 1])
X_train = X_train.astype('float32') / 255.0
X_test = X_test.reshape([10000, 28, 28, 1])
X_test = X_test.astype('float32') / 255.0
model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=[28,28,1]))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()
y_train = keras.utils.np_utils.to_categorical(y_train)
y_test = keras.utils.np_utils.to_categorical(y_test)
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100)
```

But it is taking a lot of time for execution. It is like 30 minutes per epoch. I think I am doing something wrong in my code. Can someone help me figure that out?

Answer (score 2):

Few points I want to highlight:

- Look at these lines in your code after loading mnist dataset:

  ```
  X_train = X_train.astype(np.float32) / 256.0
  X_test = X_test.astype(np.float32) / 256.0
  ```

  Why are you dividing by `256.0` ? A pixel data in an image ranges from 0-255. So, you should divide it by `255.0` to normalize it to range 0-1.
- After normalizing your data once after loading, you are normalizing it again. Check below code:

  ```
  X_train = X_train.reshape([60000, 28, 28, 1])
  X_train = X_train.astype('float32') / 255.0
  X_test = X_test.reshape([10000, 28, 28, 1])
  X_test = X_test.astype('float32') / 255.0
  ```

  Here, after reshaping you are normalizing it again. There is no need of that. Normalizing data multiple times may slow down your convergence while training the network.
- You are not passing `batch_size` value inside `model.fit` function. As per the documentation [here](https://keras.io/models/model/),

  > If unspecified, batch_size will default to 32.

  This might be the reason that it's taking more time for execution. Try to increase `batch_size` to 100, 200, etc. and then check execution time.
- If might be possible that you are training your model on cpu, instead of gpu. `60000x28x28` training data is not a small dataset.